# How to remove uploaded image(if any) from canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

In my code image is removed successfully if any, but when there are multiple images in the canvas, how do I know that I have to call Remove_image() function for how many times?
my condition is if the body finds canvas is null then upload the image else remove the uploaded image.

**This is my code**

```
cy.get('body').each((body) => {
        if (body.find(':nth-child(2) > .front-upload > :nth-child(2) > .table > .table-cell').length > 0) {

            const filepath = "Front.jpg"
            imageupload.fileuploadInput().attachFile(filepath, { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' })
            cy.wait(60000)
            cy.Flip_image()
        }
        else {

            // REMOVE ELEMENT
            cy.log('Remove Image')
           // There is 5 uploaded image that's why this function call 5 times But this is not right structure.       
            cy.Remove_image()
            cy.Remove_image()
            cy.Remove_image()
            cy.Remove_image()
            cy.Remove_image()
            
            // UPLOAD IMAGE
            cy.wait(1000)
            const filepath = "Front.jpg"
            imageupload.fileuploadInput().attachFile(filepath, { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' })
            cy.wait(60000)
            cy.Flip_image()
        }

    })
```

Comment: We can better help you if you make a snippet here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd approach it,

Assuming there are as many images as there are cells

```js
cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .front-upload > :nth-child(2) > .table')
  .then($table => {

    const imageCount = $table.find('.table-cell').length;  

    for (let i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
      cy.Remove_image()
    })

    // UPLOAD IMAGE
    cy.wait(1000)
    const filepath = "Front.jpg"
    imageupload.fileuploadInput().attachFile(filepath, { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' })
    cy.wait(60000)
    cy.Flip_image()

  })
```

If some cells may be empty, you can count `<img>` tags instead

```js
const imageCount = $table.find('img').length;
```

Comment: I like your solution. 1 suggestion though - add assertion the image is removed as part of the for-loop.

Comment: @RosenMihaylov that would be a good idea, depends on what's inside `cy.Remove_image()`, i.e what the effect is on the DOM. I can't really work out all the behavior here.